# Помощники машиниста или машинистов?

Tags: орфография, единственное-множественное-число

Как писать правильно: «Помощники машиниста» или «Помощники машинистов»?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это зависит от того, о названии профессии идёт речь или о реальных машинистах с помощниками. Первое гораздо чаще встречается ("машинист" остаётся в единственном числе - это о людях, каждый из которых является "помощником машиниста"):

> Требуются помощники машинист**а**;
>
> открыты курсы повышения квалификации помощников машинист**а**.

В случае же, когда конкретные машинисты при помощниках имеют значение, слово "машинист" предпочтительно изменять по числу (без этого будет формальная ссылка на должность, что грамматически тоже допустимо):

> За создание опасности лобового столкновения поездов судят двух
>   машинистов;
>
> помощники машинист**ов** вызваны в качестве свидетелей.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, «машиниста». С вами будет один машинист. Почитайте также [обязанности помощника машиниста](https://kedu.ru/press-center/profgid/pomoshchnik-mashinista-elektrovoza-vtoroy-nomer-ekipazha-lokomotiva). Очень интересно.

Comment: С вами - это с кем? А если слет юных помощников машинист(а/ов)?!

Comment: Все зависит от предложения. Автору стоило уточнить что он имел в виду.